# How do I connect a new trap to an old cast iron pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I replaced a lavatory in the bathroom with a new faucet and new trap, but the old 1-1/4 trap is connected to a cast iron pipe with led through the wall. I cut the old trap out, and I used a 1-1/4 connector and it is okay. I'd like to replace the old piece of trap that is leading into the cast iron pipe with a straight PVC pipe and an adapter. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You would normally cut out the piece right before - 8 inches or so before the main stack.  You then connect PVC to cast iron with a [coupling](http://www.walmart.com/ip/23474110?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227017058022&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=25357776036&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=50583912156&veh=sem).